# Weird shading fragments when rotating view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, artifacts

I'm currently trying to render an architectural model using Blender. However, when shaded there is a strange issue with the roof which I never encountered before in shading view.

I highly doubt that the issue comes from the material itself, as the material is just a basic Principled BSDF with a color and a reflection map attached (the shader came with the .obj right from ArchiCAD, other values of the shader look normal and as expected).

The issue I encounter is the following: from some perspectives everything is just fine and looks just like it should. However, if I rotate the view to certain positions, there are bands appearing that run over the roof and appear shaded in a different color. The following pictures should clarify what I mean:

View with shading as expected:
[image]

View with weird shading:

[image: Weird Shading]

The issue is not linked to unapplied Scale/Rotation/Location as I already tried those in order to solve the issue. It also is independent of the render engine as Eevee and Cycles produce the same result. Strangely, the other materials seem to work just fine (or at least I haven't found anything odd by now for any other material).

I also tried to switch the shader for another Principled BSDF in order to test certain behaviour like various Roughness/Metallic/Specularity values. When doing so, I also had a situation where the grass texture was reflecting off of a part of the roof, which makes absolutely no sense, because the entire terrain is ALWAYS below the roof, so no reflection of the grass should be possible.

I have absolutely no idea, what the issue could be and I didn't really have any idea how to google for this strange behaviour (except for search requests that where pretty broad and returned more common shading issues). So I'd be really happy for any help regarding this issue. If there is anything else needed from my end, please let me know and I'll try to provide the neccessary information asap.

In case this is of any help, I'll provide the shader settings for the roof material down below:
[image: Shader setup]

Comment: Hey have you checked if you have overlapping faces or verts? In edit mode A than M merge by distance

Comment: @EvripidisLalissidis That's actually one thing I didn't try until now. I tried it on a copy of the original model and it removed a notable number of vertices, however, it doesn't seem to resolve the problem. I gotta say that the model produced by ArchiCAD is a hot mess (like rectangles that could easily be quads being divided into the weirdest shapes ever) but that's what I gotta work with. When looking at the model up close, it doesn't look like a clipping issue though and I'd also assume clipping to look differently after shading.

Comment: you can upload a packed Blender.file at https://blend-exchange.com/ and ill have a look tomorrow morning :)